# Ambiguous resolution module Error RazorPay

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, razorpay

[image]

After adding react-native-razor-pay dependency, i am getting the following error for ambiguous resolution for react-native .

Comment: Did you got a solution for this?

Comment: No, I just included react-native razorpay in my project as a module instead of installing it as a dependency, it is working for now. But i haven't updated the module.May be you can try installing the latest version of razor pay it might be working now.